# BigQuery: NodeJS client library does not seem to respect useAvroLogicalTypes when performing a load job from Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to run a job from my nodeJS server, which loads an AVRO file on Cloud Storage into a BigQuery table. The job works perfectly, however the `date` column is loaded as type `INTEGER` in the table. I included the `useAvroLogicalTypes` param in the load job but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

If I cast the `date` column in the table using a `SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(date))` I do get the correct date, but hoping to avoid this extra transformation step. I have read everywhere that the avro logical types can be cast implicitly if the parameter is set, but I have been unable to get it to work. The table was created by the job, so there was no pre-existing schema.

Client library versions I am using are: 
**4.4.0** for `@google-cloud/bigquery` 
**4.1.2** for `@google-cloud/storage`.

AVRO SCHEMA:

```
const schema = {
    "name": "root",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      { "name": "date", "type": ["null", { "type": "long", "logicalType": "date" }]},
      { "name": "medium", "type": ["null", "string"] },
      { "name": "source", "type": ["null", "string"] },
      { "name": "campaign", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    ]
  };
```

JOB CODE

```
const options = {
    sourceFormat: 'AVRO',
    writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    useAvroLogicalTypes: true,
    datasetID,
  };

bigquery
    .dataset(datasetID)
    .table(tableID)
    .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName), options)
    .then(results => {

      res = results[0];

      // load() waits for the job to finish
      console.log(`Job ${res.id} completed.`);

      // Check the job's status for errors
      const errors = res.status.errors;

      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        E = errors;
      }
      // This kicks the execution back to where the Fiber.yield() statement stopped it
      fiber.resume();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

Sample Raw data:

```
data = [
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"(none)","source":"(direct)","campaign":"(not set)","users":3053},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"(not set)","source":"email-client","campaign":"(not set)","users":3},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"affiliate","source":"sdn","campaign":"(not set)","users":1},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"corner","campaign":"onboarding","users":1},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"custom-playlist","campaign":"fonboarding","users":1},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"deref-mail.com","campaign":"(not set)","users":2},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"faketempmail","campaign":"(not set)","users":1},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"fundx","campaign":"email_campaign","users":1},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"email-client","campaign":"(not set)","users":14},
{"date":"2019-08-01","medium":"email","source":"email-client","campaign":"100k","users":2},
]
```

I convert the date property to `long` using momentJS and underscoreJS and a simple map function:

```
data = _.map(data, row => {
    row.date = moment(row.date).isValid() ? +moment(row.date).valueOf() : null;
    return row;
  });
```

Comment: I was able to upload a '{"type": "string", "logicalType": "date"}' without issues and the BigQuery type was indeed 'DATE'. Could you please upload a sample of the raw data? This will help me to try reproducing your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your help @F10, I have included a sample data set that I have been testing with. Appreciate it. Also from your comment, it seems like you used type == string and logicalType = date, from the BQ docs and AVRO spec it seemed like the logicalType date needs to go with an INT value, and not string?

Comment: I'm going to post an answer to give a better explanation on this.

Answer (score 0):

The way you mention would be the "[default](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types)" way as the Avro logical type `date` will be stored as `INTEGER` in BigQuery when you're not using `useAvroLogicalTypes`.

This also depend on how your AVRO schema was made. For instance, I had to build an AVRO file with the schema

```
"fields":[
    {"logicaltype": "date", "type": "string", "name": "field1"}
]
```

and I uploaded my DATE data correctly by using the following code:

```
const metadata = {
      sourceFormat: 'AVRO',
      useAvroLogicalTypes: true,
      createDisposition: 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
      writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      schema: {
        fields: [
          {
            name: "field1",
            type: "DATE",
            logicalType: "STRING",
            mode: "NULLABLE"
          }
        ],
      },
      location: 'US',
    };
    const [job] = await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata);
```

Based on the data that you shared, it should work with this configuration as your `date` data is `String`.

Hope it helps.